# When are the sum of the digits of $2^n$ and $2^{n+1}$ equal and for what value of n? Stuck on this problem!

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

For $a \in Z$, let $p(a)$ be the sum of the digits of $2^a$. For instance, $2^5 =32$ and $p(5)=3+2$. For what values of $a$ is $p(a)=p(a+1)$.

How do I go about doing this?

I know that the last digits of $2^a$ end in 2,4,6, or 8. I tried writing equations to represent the digits but nothing is working so far.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71881/can-2n-and-2n1-have-the-same-digit-sum)

Comment: I dont think it is possible for $n+1$ but you will have luck with $n+6$ with or without adding the sum of digits of the sum together.

Comment: I can do it in base 2.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  digit sums should make you think of working $\bmod 3$ or $\bmod 9$